# Unity gets stuck at Converting managed assemblies to C++ for iOS build

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

After importing google ads plugin unity is unable to create a xcode project. The building process gets stuck on Converting managed assemblies to C++. I'm working on Unity 2017.3.0f3.Unity hangs at Converting managed assemblies to C++. After waiting 30 mins or so there is no progress.

Comment: This sounds like it's too specific an error for us to help with - you may have to go to Unity directly for help. Is there anything in the process list you can see that looks likely? Are there any build logs you can check? (I can't remember) Can you reproduce this with a small test project and google-ads - is there anything you can add / remove from your main project that triggers the problem? Can you try with a different version of Unity, or a different version of the Google Ads code?